# Interface from AsyncTask back to Fragment without knowing Interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

What I am trying to achive is a single AsynTask that can check if a user has access to a certain fragment in my application that can be called from various fragments.

I am not sure that this is even possible so thought I would ask here, this is my latest attempt

```
public class HasAccess extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    Context ctx;
    String AppName;
    IInterface i;
    int AccessGranted;


    public HasAccess(Context _ctx, String _AppName, IInterface _i)
    {
        this.ctx = _ctx;
        this.AppName = _AppName;
        this.i = _i;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        int UserID = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_userid", null));

        PermsTableOps PTO = new PermsTableOps(ctx);
        int AccessGranted = PTO.hasAccess(AppName,UserID);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        i.Access(AccessGranted);
    }
}
```

So basically from various fragments I would like to be able to call this task, each of these fragments has its own interface, what I want to avoid is creating an AsyncTask for each interface.

I hope this is clear enough!

Edit I think the code above is confusing the issue so I have provided a theoretical example:

Fragment 1 inherits interface 1

Fragment 2 inherits interface 2

AsyncTask 1

Both fragment 1 and fragment 2 call AsyncTask1 - I want a response sent to my fragment from the asynctask whether it is called from either fragment 1 or fragment 2, by sending in the relevant interface.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Please be more specific: you want to check if user has access to currently displayed fragment or before showing that fragment? Like make sure user has access to it and show if yes

Comment: are you sure this variable `AccessGranted` in `doInBackground` isnt shadowing the global `AccessGranted`? this is not an answer anyway

Comment: I suggest defining a [`Generic Interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html) or A `Fragment` that implements that `interface`.

Comment: @AlexanderZhak - I hope to kick the user out of the fragment when they open it

Comment: @Spurdow the line i.Access(AccessGranted) doesnt lead anywhere and errors, this is where I should have a method in my choosen Interface

Comment: Then no need in AsyncTask. There're two options: 1) check for permission before showing fragment (in an activity which handles fragmets) or 2) create a parent Fragment class from which all your fragments will be extended. In parent fragment do the check.

Comment: @Spurdow - The fragments do implement interfaces! That is my whole question? I would like to able to send in to my async task various interfaces

Comment: I cant seem to understand if this actually works, cause in you `doInBackground` return `Void`, while your `onPostExecute` has a `Integer` parameter. Actually change the `<Void,Void,Void>` to `<Void,Void,Integer>` and return this  `PTO.hasAccess(AppName,UserID);` in `doInBackground` and use it in `i.AccessGranted(integer);`